# How to create software raid on working ubuntu server with gpt?

Tags: linux, software-raid, mdadm, raid1, gpt

i have this structure of hdd on my server:

```
fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 2.7 TiB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: EA206948-7BBC-4AD9-8835-40746D07F575

Device     Start       End   Sectors    Size Type
/dev/sda1     40      2048      2009 1004.5K BIOS boot
/dev/sda2   4096 409602047 409597952  195.3G Linux RAID


Disk /dev/sdb: 2.7 TiB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: D2514683-E466-41C0-82AD-44635CA12AE8

Device     Start       End   Sectors    Size Type
/dev/sdb1     40      2048      2009 1004.5K BIOS boot
/dev/sdb2   4096 409602047 409597952  195.3G Linux RAID


Disk /dev/md2: 195.3 GiB, 209714085888 bytes, 409597824 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

How you can see total size of my hdd-s - 2,7T. Also, i have program raid for `/`. This is `/dev/sda2` and `/dev/sdb2`. How i can create other partition with `/dev/sda3` and `/dev/sdb3` with size 500GB on both disks and make `Linux RAID 1`, like i am using on `/dev/sda2` and `/dev/sdb2` ? 
I tried with using of `fdisk`. I made two partitions with 500GB for each. I made `mdadm`:
`mdadm --create /dev/md3 --metadata=0.90 --level=mirror --raid-devices=2 /dev/sda3 /dev/sdb3`
and i added `ARRAY /dev/md3 UUID=3a5d7bb4:7f8f4e1f:a4d2adc2:26fd5302` to `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf`. also i added my `/dev/md3` to `fstab`, but after reboot, my system was not loaded. Where i have error ? How can i do this operation ? How can i do to have for `/dev/sda3` and `/dev/sdb3` `Linux Raid` and not `Linux filesystem`

Comment: `but after reboot, my system was not loaded.` what exactly was the error?  What do you mean by 'not loaded'? Did the system not boot at all, or what?  What Linux distro?  For some, you might need to regenerated your initrd, when updating your mdadm.conf.

Answer (score 0):

It seems /dev/sda3 is missing a filesystem (fs).

Use mkfs to create the fs of your choice and edit /etc/fstab accordingly.